# Cant write string to attr_accessor in ruby

Tags: ruby

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. I want to be able to capitalize any string that is being added later in the code through the method `titles` .

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :book_title

  def initialize
       @book_title = String.new
     end

  def titles
    book_title.capitalize
  end

end

@book = Book.new
puts @book.titles = "steve jobs"
```

Because when I execute it, I get `` undefined method `titles=' for #<Book:0x007fbd25813d98 @book_title=""> (NoMethodError) ``

Comment: You created `titles` but call `titles=`.

Comment: so you mean something like ```def titles=(value)``` ? In that case I get ```undefined method `capitalize'``` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish. You're adding an `attr_accessor` for `book_title`, not for `titles` (which isn't a variable at all). You need to call

```
puts @book.book_titles = "Steve Jobs"
```

in order to set (and print) the title.

If you're trying to pass a title to `titles` and have that method capitalize the title and set `@book_title` to that, you need to declare it as an assignment method using `=`, pass in the parameter `title`, and actually set `@book_title` to that. Something like this

```
def titles= title
  @book_title = title.capitalize
end
```

Currently your `titles` method only returns the capitalized local variable `book_title`, which doesn't exist (it needs the `@` to reference the instance variable).

Comment: Yes but you see I want to capitalize on it too. I was wondering how can I pass it or write on book_title through a method

Comment: So if later i pass in ```puts @book.titles = "james"``` . It should capitalize james to James also.

Comment: Edited my answer to be an assignment method. I think that's what you're looking for (though you may need to finesse the capitalization aspect).

Comment: But it is not accepting a value after = . For example ```puts @book.titles = "steve jobs"``` .  And there is already an ```  attr_accessor :book_title``` too.

Comment: Yes, there is an `attr_accessor` for `book_title` but not for `titles`, so you need to define a reader for `titles`.

Comment: The program works fine when I write a method as ```def titles(value)``` and ```puts @book.titles("steve jobs")``` . But i need to have it the way i mentioned in the question :). Which is ```puts @book.titles = "steve jobs"```. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: You are. I edited my answer with the method `def titles= title`, which does what you want.

Comment: Yes fixing the capitalization aspect is what I need help with. And even if I do an attr_reader for title. It wont be for the method title.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method for title capitalization, so you'll need to write your own. Maybe scan through, find all spaces, and set the next character in upcase (though there are some subtler rules about titles).

Comment: Here is my updated code - http://pastebin.com/je2j1Zgz . But it doesnt capitalize :P.

Comment: It capitalizes the way `String#capitalize` does: sets the first character in upper case and the rest in lower. You'll need to write your own capitalizer.

Comment: but its not even capitalizing the first letter.

Comment: Check `@book.book_title` -- it should be correct. Apparently Ruby assigner methods return the values they are passed, not the last line in the method (unlike other methods), so the `puts` statement just prints that value.

Comment: maybe something is wrong on my end. I will look it up. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

It's saying "undefined method titles=" because you haven't defined a method named `titles=`. Instead, `attr_accessor` (one of Ruby's many [misleading names](http://codelikethis.com/lessons/ruby/bad_names)) defines two methods, in your case named `book_title` and `book_title=`. Then you add `titles`. None of these is named `titles=` (the equal sign is significant).

Your `titles` method (by the way, you should figure out if it's singular or plural) is redundant with `book_title`, which will lead to confusion. As someone seeing this code for the first time -- or once again, after a break -- how am I to know which method to call?

You need to decide whether to capitalize the string on the way in (during the setter) or on the way out (during the getter). No matter what you do, I recommend that you stop using `attr_accessor` for a bit, and just explicitly define a getter and a setter (`def title` and `def title=`) until it's clear in your mind what they do. The `attr_accessor` macro is just a shorthand; you should learn longhand first.

Comment: Something like this? http://pastebin.com/Jp1dxMa4 . Not working though. It returns the string without capitalizing.

Comment: When you `puts` *during* an assignment, things get weird (not sure why). Try `@book.title = 'moby dick'; puts @book.title;` (and see my [test-first lab on strings](http://testfirst.org/live/learn_ruby/simon_says) to figure out why the result is `"Moby dick"`).